# Request.IsAuthenticated not displaying correctly for custom made Login system for ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I made a custom Login system for my ASP.NET MVC app, using this article for help: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/482546/Creating-a-custom-user-login-form-with-NET-Csharp

I've all all the controllers, models and views for the system and they all work fine and are saving data to a MySQL DB. Problem is that my Request.IsAuthenticated is not working as intended, displaying "Log Out" when a user is logged in.
The language used is Danish (Brugernavn = Username).
Let me know if you need more information.

Here is the code in my _Layout.cshtml file:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    @Html.Encode(User.Identity.Name)
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log Ud", "Logout", "User")</li>
                }
                else
                {
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Opret Bruger", "Register", "User")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log Ind", "Login", "User")</li>
                }
```

My UserController:

```
// GET: User
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(Models.User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (user.OpretNyBruger(user.Brugernavn, user.Password))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Kan ikke oprette bruger.");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(Models.User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (user.IsValid(user.Brugernavn, user.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Brugernavn, user.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Forkert brugernavn eller password!");
            }
        }
        return View(user);
    }
    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

My View for the Login:

```
@model RingkoebingSkjern.Models.User
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Login";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login fejlede. Tjek venligst dine 
oplysninger.");
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Brugernavn)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Brugernavn)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Brugernavn)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(u => u.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(u => u.RememberMe)
            @Html.LabelFor(u => u.RememberMe)
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
    </fieldset>
</div>
}
```

Comment: Well, personally, I'd say your problem is creating a custom login system. There could be all manner of things "wrong" in your custom system, preventing the user from being recognized as logged in, and without seeing your entire project, it's virtually impossible to say what the issue is. And, of course, the fact that you're having this issue at all indicates that you don't have full test coverage. If you used something like Identity, not only would you have a fully tested and secure system, but you'd also have a entire community of people who can help you. Currently, you have none of that.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. This is a student project, so strict security is not a requirement. I have used Identity before and it works flawlessly, but we wanted a custom login system for our project, since we want to store all out data (including login info) in a single DB. I will try other methods, thanks again.

Comment: @user1696992 The issue is that it is not displaying "Log Ud" and "Log Ind" for logged in and logged out users.